# network routing multiple default gateway for docker

Tags: networking, docker, firewall

I have a webserver host with docker. I wish to attach 2 floating IP on this instance. but at the end docker only serve one of the floating IP to public.

I had followed : 
https://www.notion.so/bigstack/Dual-WAN-routing-5e4f25a6f7a74a658ec1ead16af86968#57acc41726b749168da9c07c7ed78c0d

for multiple default gateway setup

Adding Rule - ens3

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev ens3 src 192.168.100.38 table 100
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev ens3 table 100
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.100.38/32 table 100
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.100.38/32 table 100
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 metric 100 dev ens3
```

Adding Rule - ens4

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.101.0/24 dev ens4 src 192.168.101.24 table 200
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.101.1 dev ens4 table 200
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.101.24/32 table 200
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.101.24/32 table 200
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.101.1 metric 200 dev ens4
```

IP route & rules

```
ubuntu@bs-web-test: /var/www/html
$ ip rule show                                                                                                            [11:47:28]
0:  from all lookup local
32762:  from all to 192.168.101.24 lookup 200
32763:  from 192.168.101.24 lookup 200
32764:  from all to 192.168.100.38 lookup 100
32765:  from 192.168.100.38 lookup 100
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ubuntu@bs-web-test: /var/www/html
$ ip route show                                                                                                           [11:47:32]
default via 192.168.100.1 dev ens3 metric 100
default via 192.168.101.1 dev ens4 metric 200
169.254.169.254 via 192.168.101.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.24 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 192.168.100.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.38 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-7399437930c9 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-9bf79dfaaf1d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1
192.168.100.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.38
192.168.101.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.24
```

Docker - I have create a webserver with docker serve at port 8080

Apache2(hostlevel) - installed apache2 with apt, serve at port 80

Scan floating IP with nmap

```
$ nmap 45.x.x.x
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-20 11:32 CST
Nmap scan report for 45.x.x.x
Host is up (0.089s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.53 seconds

$ nmap 119.x.x.x
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-20 11:32 CST
Nmap scan report for isp.chiefchief.net.tw (119.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Test with curl

```
$ curl 192.168.100.38:8080
<h1>Welcome</h1>

$ curl 119.x.x.x:8080
<h1>Welcome</h1>

curl 192.168.101.24:8080
<h1>Welcome</h1>

$ curl 45.x.x.x:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 45.x.x.x port 8080: Operation timed out

$ curl 192.168.100.38
<h1> This is Apache2 Test page </h1>

curl 192.168.101.24
<h1> This is Apache2 Test page </h1>

$ curl 119.x.x.x
<h1> This is Apache2 Test page </h1>

$ curl 45.x.x.x
<h1> This is Apache2 Test page </h1>
```

Question: Where there are no issues with curl the webserver(docker) through local network, but not working with public ip ?

Thank you for reading, appreciated any help ~

Comment: Since you are routing, you also must add *all* relevant routes from the Docker networks to your additional tables and add additional rules looking them up

Comment: hint: `ip route get from 192.168.101.24 8.8.8.8` vs `ip route get from 172.19.0.2 iif br-9bf79dfaaf1d 8.8.8.8`. That way you can test everything without sending a single packet anywhere

Comment: Also your link requires a login, so isn't a proper link. It's thus impossible to know if your tutorial already addressed your problem or not.